# Error del proveedor subyacente en Open

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc, linq

Tengo un error que me dice: Error del proveedor subyacente en Open, y en 
en innerexcepcion dice:

> {"Valor de tiempo de espera caducado. El periodo de tiempo de espera
>   se agotó durante la fase previa al inicio de sesión. Es posible que la
>   conexión agotara el tiempo de espera mientras esperaba que el servidor
>   completara el proceso de inicio de sesión y respondiera; o bien, al
>   intentar crear varias conexiones activas.  El tiempo invertido al
>   intentar conectarse a este servidor fue: [Previo al inicio de sesión]
>   inicialización=13443; protocolo de enlace=1; [Inicio de sesión]
>   inicialización=0; autenticación=34; [Tras el inicio de sesión]
>   completo=4176; "}

La linea del error donde dice: Dim total_listadoNoticia = list_noticia.ToList.Count

```
Dim list_noticia = From f In db.NOTICIA Select New With {.IdNoticia =    f.IdNoticia, .TituloNoticia = f.TituloNoticia, .DescripcionNoticia = f.DescripcionNoticia, .FechaPublicacionNoticia = f.FechaPublicacionNoticia}
Dim total_listadoNoticia = list_noticia.ToList.Count ' aquí se cae
```

la cantidad de datos que se lista el `Count` son bastantes, de hecho uno de los atributos de la tabla `NOTICIA` es binario (f.FotoPortada), pero se lo quite.

En la `webconfig` le puse esto para solucionar el problema:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" maxRequestLength="4194304" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="100" />
```

pero nada.

Este problema ocurre solo la primera vez después de ejecutar el `Visual Studio`, si lo vuelvo a ejecutar, no aparece el error.

Me gustaría saber como optimizar mi `query` de linq haciéndola mas eficiente, evitando este tipo de problema y si no fuese posible, como darle mas memoria o alguna capacidad en la `webconfig` o donde sea para evitar este tipo de problemas.

codigo completo:

```
Function partialListadoNoticia(ByVal pag As Integer) As ActionResult
    Using db As New BD_LOSCOPIHUESEntities1
        Dim cant_filas As Integer = 5
        Dim ind_pag As Integer = (cant_filas - 1) * pag


        Dim l As New ListadoNoticiasViewModel
        Dim listadoNoticia_q = (From noti In db.NOTICIA.Include("FOTO") Select noti Order By noti.FechaPublicacionNoticia Descending)
        Dim total_listadoNoticia = db.NOTICIA.Count

        Dim ultima_paginaDouble As Decimal = total_listadoNoticia / cant_filas
        Dim ultima_paginaEntero As Integer = Decimal.Round(ultima_paginaDouble, 0)

        If ultima_paginaDouble > ultima_paginaEntero Then
            ultima_paginaEntero = ultima_paginaEntero + 1
        End If

        l.listadoNoticias = listadoNoticia_q.Skip(ind_pag).Take(cant_filas).ToList()
        ViewData("totalListadoNoticia") = total_listadoNoticia
        ViewData("ultimaPagina") = ultima_paginaEntero
        ViewData("pagina_actual") = pag ' esto es para paginación

        Return View(l)
    End Using

End Function
```

En `Dim total_listadoNoticia = db.NOTICIA.Count`, es donde indica el error

Comment: Recuerda que la ejecucion de la query de linq swe realiza cuando defines el ToList() es por eso que alli se marca el problema. Ahora bien solo quieres contar las noticias o tambien requieres obtenerlas ?

Comment: En un caso necesito saber cuantas tuplas hay en la tabla noticia, el total, pero mas adelante necesitaré obtener algunos atributos de la noticia como lista.

Comment: Cuantas filas estas recibiendo en el resultado?

Comment: estoy recibiendo 32 filas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que sucede si solo defines

```
Dim total_listadoNoticia As Integer = db.NOTICIA.Count();
```

Si la idea es solo contar las entidades de la tabla.

---

Si la entidad tiene un campo con una foto sería recomendable implementar `Table Splitting`, con este podrias mapear varias clases de .net a una misma tabla pudiendo recuperar solo algunos de los campos básicos.

[[Entity Framework][Code First] Dividir Tabla](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2013/09/entity-frameworkcode-first-dividir.html)

En tu caso las propiedades principales las defines en la clase principal y por ejemplo, el campo de la imagen lo defines en una entidad separada, de esta forma al recuperar con la query no penalizas la consulta.

---

Podrias ver de ampliar el timeout de ese comando

```
Using db As New BD_LOSCOPIHUESEntities1
   db.Database.CommandTimeout = 180;

End Using
```

[Set database timeout in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788972/set-database-timeout-in-entity-framework)

De esta forma le darias tiempo a que ejecute al iniciar la aplicacion

Comment: si coloco:
Dim total_listadoNoticia As Integer = db.NOTICIA.Count();

da el mismo problema.
¿Será que incluye a todos los atributos de la tabla?

Comment: No, no los incluye, es mas si usaras el Sql Profiler de Sql Server podrias analizar la query que ejecuta. el servicio de Sql Server esta en la red local? o te conectas de forma remota por internet o una vpn?

Comment: el servicio de Sql server, está en la red local, de hecho del mismo visual studio

Comment: Lo otra forma forma sería intentar hacerlo con procedimiento almacenado.

Comment: No veo como un procedure podrias solucionar el problema, ademas si vas por ese camino pierdes la ventaja de usar un ORM. Intentaste implementando el Table Split que comento en el articulo?

Comment: tenía pensado usar procedure con algo asi:



Dim resultado As New SqlParameter()
            resultado.ParameterName = "@ResultadoOut"
            resultado.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            resultado.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int
            resultado.Size = 50
            Dim total_listadoNoticia = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec Noticia_ObTotalRows , @ResultadoOut OUTPUT", resultado)

Pero por lo que me dices, es mejor usar split?

Comment: @Danilo si la tecnica del split resuleve el problema seria el mejor camino ya que dejar que el ORM genere el comando. El tema de evitar procedure pasa porque una vez que tomas ese camino vas a implementar todo con procedure y si haces eso para que quieres un ORM, vuelve a usar ado.net que sera mas practico. Solo en casos muy especiales donde hay muchos join y tablas relaciondas se aconseja usar el procedure proque el linq seria complejo, para un simple count de registro no se justifica

Comment: @Danilo Igual me cuesta cree que solo el db.NOTICIA.Count(); genere un timeout, estas seguro que solo defines esa unica linea o hay algun otro linq ejecutandose ? si ejecutas la query linq mas de una vez siempre da timeout? lo planteo porque a veces la primer ejecucion puede fallar porque tiene que parsear la query y eso demora, pero la segunda al tenerla en cache se eejcuta mas rapido.

Comment: @Danilo pero cual es la que genera el timeout ? porque habias comentado que el count era quien lo generaba. Es muy distinto si lo produce el count a si lo realiza otra query diferente, es mas porque realizas un Include de foto ? la idea no era que la quitabas de la query, o al menos eso comentaste en el planteo del problema

Comment: A parte de esa query: Dim total_listadoNoticia = db.NOTICIA.Count tengo otro linq en el mismo metodo del controler: Dim listadoNoticia_q = (From noti In db.NOTICIA.Include("FOTO") Select noti Order By noti.FechaPublicacionNoticia Descending) pero como dije antes, se me cae cuando lleva el Count y es verdad que en la primera ejecución falla, pero a la segunda se trae del cache ejecutandose mas rapido

Comment: Explicaré mas detallado, primero tengo dos query: Dim listadoNoticia_q = (From noti In db.NOTICIA.Include("FOTO") Select noti Order By noti.FechaPublicacionNoticia Descending)

esto es para incluirlo en una vista parcial, e incluyo la FOTO, para poder mostrar las fotos asociada a la NOTICIA en la vista, hasta ahí, todo bien, pero al incluir otra query para obtener el total de registro de la tabla NOTICIA(Dim total_listadoNoticia = db.NOTICIA.Count ), se produce la falla.

Comment: Ademas, utilizo el mismo listadoNoticia_q usando Skip y take, para optimizar la consulta:
 l.listadoNoticias = listadoNoticia_q.Skip(ind_pag).Take(cant_filas).ToList()

Comment: @leando, incluí el codigo completo

Comment: ok, pero has mencionado algo clave, este problema se produce en la primer ejecucion y no en las siguiente, entonces no es un problma del codigo sino de esa primer carga. Si estas ejecutando desde el VS esto es previsible que suceda, la cuestion es que no pase cuando publicas en el IIS

Comment: Ok, entendí, gracias por tu respuesta. :)